# Leave event on OutlinedTextField

Tags: keyboard, android-jetpack-compose, outlined-text-fields

How to catch leave event from OutlinedTextField to close keyboard?

```
fun LabelName(nameUpdate: String = "", name: (String) -> Unit) {
   OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(end = 20.dp),
        value = nameUpdate,
        onValueChange = {
            name(manageLength(it))
        },
        label = {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = if ( nameUpdate.isNotEmpty() ) R.string.name else R.string.add_new_name))
        }
}
```

But then I click on the button, OutlinedTextField stayed focusable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to hide the keyboard then use `keyboardController` only. I also recommend changing the keyboard button to done, as I did in the example below. And if you want to turn off the focus, you need to add `LocalFocusManager` so that after pressing the done button on the keyboard on the phone, the focus will be immediately set to `OutlinedTextField`.

```
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
val focusRequesterManager = LocalFocusManager.current

Column {
    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(end = 20.dp),
        value = nameUpdate,
        onValueChange = {
            name(manageLength(it))
        },
        label = {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = if ( nameUpdate.isNotEmpty() ) R.string.name else R.string.add_new_name))
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onDone = {
                keyboardController?.hide()
                focusRequesterManager.clearFocus()
            }
        )
    )
}
```